# Regular Expression with [^"\]

Tags: regex, string

for the regular expression [^"]

I have four strings to check whether if follows with this rule

"abc\ndef\"ghi" (this is correct)
"\\" (correct)
"abc"def" (this doesn't follow the rule, I think it's because that the string does not contain a \ )
"abcd\" (this is also incorrect)

Can someone explain to me why the first two are in accordance with [^"] while the last two are not? I think [^"] means the string without the character " and \, am I getting it right?

Comment: Please show exactly what code you are using to check whether a string "follows this rule" or how you are using whatever tool/website you're using to do this check.

Answer (score 2):

\ is a negation of special characters into a literals.

"abc\ndef\"ghi" works because \" is a literal character " leaving quotes at the beginning and the end.

"\" works because the first \ makes the second \ a literal character \ the quotes have not been affected.

"abc"def" does not work because you have an unclosed quotation and "abc" is a string but def are undefined characters.

"abcd\" does not work because \" has made " in to the literal character ". Therefore making an unclosed quotation and abcd are then also undefined.